# Using subversion with large directory

Tags: svn

I have a pretty large directory /var/www/ on my linux Ubuntu server.  In that directory there are a handful of files I want to use subversion on.  How can I set this up?  Set-by-step would be helpful I'm new to svn.

So far I have don't this:

```
svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /svn
svn mkdir file:///svn/www/ -m "Created www directory"
```

For example: In my /var/www/ directory there are a lot of files and subdirectories. I only want to use svn on foo.html, bar.php, and a directory example/

after the necessary files are in the svn there how can I make changes and commit them to svn?

I hope that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: SVN isn't the best match for this scenario. Do you really have to use it?

Comment: I was told to use SVN.  I agree, this doesn't seem very helpful in this situation.

Comment: Good thing you weren't told to use notepad.exe. Go back and tell the teller that their telling is more like trolling.

Comment: Okay, so is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
REPO=file:///svn
cd /var/www
svn co $REPO/www .
svn add example foo.html bar.php
svn ci -m "initial checkin"
svn up
```

You might also want to do this (still in `/var/www`):

```
svn ps svn:ignore "*" .
svn ci -m "ignore other stuff"
svn up
```

**Edit**:
The `svn:ignore` pattern hides stuff in the output of `svn status` *ONLY IF* the item is unknown to svn and would show up as `?`. You can still add files/dirs with "svn add" and changes to managed dirs/files are still tracked.

Since you are interested only in certain files/dirs this seems to be a good default in your case. You can do the same in `example` if there is stuff you don't want to version.

Comment: so in the `svn ps svn:ignore "*" .` command can I replace "*" with files and directories I want to be ignored?

Comment: so now lets say I edit a file which is in example/  how do I commit those changed to SVN?

Comment: @Corey: The [Basic Usage](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.tour) of Subversion is described in _the book_ quite good.